# php store session variable in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, variables, session

I have a website in PHP. I try to store the session variable `$_SESSION['user_name']` to a mysql database when a logged in user visits a specific webpage on my site.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user1";
$password = "user1";
$dbname = "payment";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users 
VALUES ('.$_SESSION['user_name'].')';

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Error message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /opt/lampp/htdocs/succes.php on line 16

Tried a bunch of things but can't figure it out. What is wrong here?

Comment: 1. Where did you started your session? 2. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `session_start()` at the beginning of your script (before using any `$_SESSION` variables). Also, you need quotes around the variable in you query:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users 
VALUES ("'.$_SESSION['user_name'].'")';
```

Please note that this is ***not*** safe; you are wide open to SQL injection. Instead, you should use prepared statements:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user1";
$password = "user1";
$dbname = "payment";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users 
VALUES (?)';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user_name']);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks for letting me know this is vulnerable to sql injection. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Before you use any `$_SESSION` variables you need to call `session_start()`.

Of topic a bit though, something to look into `PDO`. It can be a bit a tad slower than `mysqli()` however supports many more Database types. Here is a good article on [Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) explaining some of the differences as well as explaining essential security steps.

If I could be a bit biased I have created a PHP Class for PDO Connections which can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/TJohnson93/gutsy)

Comment: Thanks i will keep an eye on it.